# C++ is executing a function before its called?

Tags: c++, function, execute

Hell all. This problem is driving me up the wall as I cant figure out what i'm doing wrong. All I want is to collect to variables and pass them into a function, however as soon as a input the first variable the function runs?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void avg_rain(string, string);
int main()
{
    string file, unit;

    //Prompt user for file names, and assign to character array
    cout << "Please type the file names with extentions that you would like to open, seperate file names with spaces. \nfile name(s) :";
    cin >> file;

    //Prompt user for measurement unit
    cout << "Please type the unit you would like measurments to be converted to (mm, cm, in)\nUnit : ";
    cin >> unit;

    //execute function with passed through parameters
    avg_rain(file, unit);

    system("pause");
return 0;
}

void avg_rain(string ffile ,string funit )
{
    cout << ffile;
}
```

Even though  don't type anything for the second variable, this is my output.

[OUTPUT:]

```
Please type the file names with extentions that you would like to open, seperate file names with spaces.

file name(s) :hello world
Please type the unit you would like measurments to be converted to (mm, cm, in)

Unit : hello

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: The assumption begged in the title is "not possible".

Comment: It's because of the space in the file name. Use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Hell all - probably not a good way to start a post. But then again I am a queer atheist poof. So I will be going to he'll.

Comment: `>>`'s default behaviour is to stop after a single whitespace-delimited token. Basically it reads one and only one word. You want behaviour more like Option 2 in this linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301

Comment: It seems that getline has fixed the issue! thanks very much, I spent way to much time trying to figure out this issue!